# Angularjs Json Data not displayed from Asp.net WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

Trying to learn Angularjs by building on a working example
The original example displayed a simple string on the button click.
I am trying to modify to display a table of data returned from a C# WebMethod

My WebMethod seenms to be OK - I can step into it and a JSON string is returned
like:

```
[
  {"Code":"Code1","Desc":"Code1 Desc"},
  {"Code":"Code2","Desc":"Code2 Desc"},
   ....
]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleAngularjs.Test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="codeapp">

  <div ng-controller="CodeController" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>


    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Desc</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="code in myData.codes">
        <td>{{code.Code}}</td>
        <td>{{code.Desc}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>

  </div>

   <script>
           angular.module("codeapp", [])
           .controller("CodeController", function ($scope, $http) {

               $scope.myData = {};

               $scope.myData.codes = [];

               $scope.myData.doClick = function (item, event) {

                   $http.post('Test1.aspx/GetAllCodes', { data: {} })
                     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         //$scope.myData.fromServer = data.d;
                         $scope.myData.codes = data;
                     })
                     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                         $scope.status = status;
                     });



               }


           }).config(function ($httpProvider) {

               $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

               $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

           });
  </script>


</body>

</html>





[WebMethod]
        public static string GetAllCodes()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQL2012;Initial Catalog=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;Password=xxxx;User ID=xxxx"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "SELECT Code=TheCode, [Desc]=TheDescription FROM Codes ", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    serializer.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
                    string sJson = serializer.Serialize(rows);
                    return (sJson);
                }
```

I did some more testing
If I create a list manually to look like my Json list back from db - I can display the manually 
built list but not the one generated from the Json gotten from server

Here is screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have run into some CORS issues (http://enable-cors.org/). Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

If CORS is your issue you will just need to add CORS support to your server by adding " Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " to the header in your response.
Here are more details on how to implement it:
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Hi thanks but I am getting no errors - I modified my original post after some more digging - I can display the JSON data from the server in a text field but cannot in a table. If I build a list similar to what the server send me - I can display that in a text field and also in a table. I am confused that data looks the same in format